# R: Connect/assign values of two overlapping data sets

Tags: r, compare, dataframe, intersection, overlap

I need you beloved help...

I have two datasets. One assigning person names to tradeIDs, the other assigning person IDs to (the same kind of) tradeIDs. I want to find out, which person has which ID.

**Data:**

```
personID    tradeID     Name    tradeID
123         10      |   Bob     7
123         5       |   Bob     8
210         1       |   Jack    3
210         7       |   Jack    11
210         8       |   Paul    5
988         11      |   Paul    10
988         8       |
```

**Problem:**

I want to find out the overlap/intersection of the tradeIDs, so I will know which name belongs to which personID.

**Result** *(should look like the following)*

```
personID    Name
123         Paul
210         Bob
988         Jack
```

**Difficulties:**

- The overlap has different number of elements (Bob & 210)
- TradeIDs have multiple connections to different personIDs and names (tradeID 8)
- The overlap does not have to be 100% (Jack & 988)

**Ideas & trials**

- Tried: data frame comparison library && the reshape library (didn't offer any useful methods)
- Idea: Create vectors of personID and names && compare the vectors (didn't know how to make the vector) && connect the vectors with the highest overlap

Is there a way to solve this problem e.g. by data frame comparison?

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is:

1. Merge the two together
2. Compare within each name to see if it has matched more than one personID (bad!)
3. If everything checks out, drop the duplicates

So something like:

```
datA <- data.frame(personID=c( 123,123,210,210,210,988,988 ),tradeID=c( 10,5,1,7,8,11,8) )
datB <- data.frame(name=c("B","B","J","J","P","P"), tradeID=c( 7,8,3,11,5,10 ) )
mgd <- merge(datA,datB)
library(taRifx)
stopifnot( all( by(mgd$personID,as.factor(mgd$name),distinct) <=1 ) )
result <- subset(mgd, !duplicated(mgd$name),select=c(-tradeID) )
```

This fails on the stopifnot, because Bob is associated with personID 210 and 988, which is likely a typo in your example data....  If that's removed, it works well:

```
datA[7,"tradeID"] <- 12
mgd <- merge(datA,datB)
result <- subset(mgd, !duplicated(mgd$name),select=c(-tradeID) )
result
  personID name
1      123    P
2      210    B
5      988    J
```

Comment: As a side note, the fact that your answer winds up being "PB&J" makes me happy.

Comment: Hey gsk3! Thank you for the early reply! Unfortunately the 7 value for Bob was not a typo error. In your modification the name-values become distinct, so thats why is solvable --- From just looking at the data, it is the most logic answer that Bob is Nr. 210, because it overlaps 7 & 8 (66% of the 3 values of 210). For 988 Bob only overlaps 1 (50% of the bigger "vector"). Merging gives you all the possible paths from personID to name via tradeID... Do you know what my problem is?

Comment: Well you need to decide on an algorithm then.  What should 988 be assigned to, since it's a 50/50 tie?  You can use `mgd <- merge(datA,datB,all=TRUE)` to see the full merge table, and from there tally up the names by personID to get counts.